# Xamarin - There is a way to Highlight some Fields on a page?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I mean: I would like to do a Onboarding tutorial but not with images. Instead, highlighting some points of the App.
I am thinking about using a View, setting background opacity and highlighting itens that I want, like a Button for example... I just don´t know how can I do it. There is a way?
Also I looked for any plugin, but no success at all.

[image: example]

Comment: I did this for a client a while back. It was not a trivial thing to do. I don't have access to the code any more, but IIRC, I used [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) for most of it. Basically I had to get the coordinates and size of the item that I wanted to highlight, and then use that info to setup the popup page. Basically the popup page appeared over the page, but I set the transparency so it all looked like one page. Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: @Andrew BTW I started trying to do something like this, but it's not simple... but thanksss

Comment: Upload an image to explain what you expect would help

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you please explain in detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I am attaching an image.

Comment: @Shaw check the image please...

Comment: Overlay page is one way to go. Another is to place an object in the same location (that will perform your highlight) and ensure that it is painted AFTER the item to be highlighted. XAML is interpreted top down.

Comment: A simple way I can imagine is to put an image like this on the same page in the app inside a Grid view, though you don't like an image. Even for highlighting one component at a time, multiple images overlay can do, won't cost much

Comment: @Andrew Do you remember how did you get the coordinates of the items?

Comment: https://vladislavantonyuk.azurewebsites.net/articles/Interactive-app-tutorial-in-.NET-MAUI

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**: Are you talking about text and icons floating on the background?

If yes, you can try to use [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout) to achieve this.

You can place a front layout to overlay the back layout. Here, you can set a transparent background for the front layout.

**Question 2**: If you click on a button in the upper image, will the upper layout switch to a different upper layout?

If yes, you can start by placing the floating icons and text on the upper layout as you want.

Then you can display or hide the icons and texts based on the touching event.

**Notes:**

I've implemented similar functions before, and the icons and fonts on the upper layer are designed in advance by my art colleagues.

Comment: I am not a good xamarin developer. So, I am having some difficult with it. What I as thinking about was something easier like: Supposing that I have Icons, buttons, whatever. When the user click in one Button, I show the same page, but with a 50% of transparency page. But I need to keep this Button with 100% transparence. But as I am a "newbie", I don´t know.